# how to determine if a picture is explicit

Tags: api, artificial-intelligence, machine-learning, computer-vision

I'm looking for a way to determine whether a picture is explicit (is Safe For Work ) or not.

I am currently looking for an API that is capable of doing it, but so far I didn't have any success.

One of the ideas I had was to use the google search API and provide a URL to a picture, and looking whether or not it is in the results when safeSearch is enabled, but it will fail on a picture that was added before the crawler got to it.

Alternatively, I'm looking for pointers regarding what to look for in an image to determine how SFW it is. Any suggestions regarding shapes, colors or patterns?

Comment: Haha :) I can imagine how much fun it would be to collect training samples ... for science!

Comment: given that my current "dirty" solution is to simply calculate the ratio of beige in the picture, a picture of an IKEA beige couch fails my test. And that picture is also a "training sample"

Comment: @iliaden, don't forget internationalization. You need an adjustable  beige threshold of 0.1% for Iran and 99.9% for The Netherlands.

Comment: I am aware of that. And that is why I'm asking for pointers regarding how to write it. "Fuzzy" shape matching *may* work, but once again, I'm expecting too many false positives.

Comment: @iliaden: Jokes aside, I know this has been researched and googling will reveal some skin-tone + people-detector based algorithm.

Comment: someone had suggested auto posting it on 4chan and looking for "MOAR" in the comments => nfsw, nothing => sfw, banned=>CP

Comment: @bronzebeard: that seems like a very reliable algorithm, but its runtime is way too long

Comment: :D heh, you are not considering it, are you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As promised, a SFW [paper](http://www.esprockets.com/papers/rowley-jing-baluja-2006.pdf) from Google researchers and a [patent](http://www.google.com/patents/about?id=DoCnAAAAEBAJ) for your study procured from this [blog entry](http://feedproxy.google.com/~r/VisionwangComputerVisionExpertBlog/~3/I2QVh05wMBQ/).

Comment: thanks! I've found a few mathematical models that would "work" - but it will take a while to implement. but thanks for the advice

Comment: care to post those models? also seeing that most image processing books have at least one Lena picture, this seems quite in tradition! :)

Answer (score 1):

One of my colleagues led the development of the porn classification technology at one of the largest web companies. I will share what he told me about the development of the filter.

1. The definition of what is explicit varying greatly among jurisdictions so what is considered explicit in the US might not be in other parts of the world and vice-versa. So models need to take into account the users origin.
2. A purely imaged based approach is almost impossible to use effectively at web scale. The feature space is very complex in terms of how humans judge what is explicit and what is not and developing appropriate feature extraction technology for images proved to be exceedingly difficult.
3. Some of the most predictive features are the text on pages that link to the images. These are among the easiest features to develop also.
4. Building labeled training sets is very difficult since classifying porn and other explicit content for 8 hours a day tends to take a toll on the labelers. Because of this the turn over is fairly high with almost no one lasting a year.
5. Getting a high accuracy from the classifiers is still very, very difficult. They worked on it with several PhD's and a very experienced team and still did not achieve the accuracy that you are probably looking for.

If you have a more constrained problem space you can probably achieve a higher accuracy. If you are using image features only the algorithm or model will probably not generalize well and will have a high false positive rate. Best of luck.

Comment: I'm currently implementing an image scanner based on publications that were made in the last 2 years regarding skin detection in photographs, and I'm trying to classify "explicitness" based on the skin layout in images. The goal is still to make a single, not necessarily scalable image scanner that only takes an image as the input. I assume that I don't have any links to the web page it was found on.  Even worse, imagine that the web page is imgur.com - it's almost impossible to get any relevant data from the hosting site.

Answer (score 0):

See papers:

Detection of Pornographic Digital Images
Jorge A. Marcial-Basilio, Gualberto Aguilar-Torres, Gabriel Sánchez-Pérez, L. Karina Toscano-
Medina, and Héctor M. Pérez-Meana

Pornography Detection Using Support Vector Machine
Yu-Chun Lin (林語君) Hung-Wei Tseng (曾宏偉) Chiou-Shann Fuh

Image-Based Pornography Detection
Rigan Ap-apid
De La Salle University, Manila, Philippines

You can also take some hints from existing implementations e.g.:

"The Porn Detection Stick uses advanced image analyzing algorithms that categorize images as potentially harmful by identifying facial features, flesh tone colors, image back grounds, body part shapes, and more."